# Specifying template parameter with a Typedef

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++11

I want to able to pass two joined iterators as one to take advantage of some stl like algorithms (such as TBB) so I am making a custom iterator that joins them but am hitting some stumbling blocks.

I need to specialize iterator, however it won't let me generically specify a template parameter.

Like so:

```
template<typename IT1, typename IT2>
struct multi_iter : public std::iterator<
                            std::output_iterator_tag,
                            std::pair<IT1::value_type&, IT2::value_type&> >
{
.
:
```

However it will let me do this, but this is not what I am after

```
template<typename IT1, typename IT2>
struct multi_iter : public std::iterator<
                            std::output_iterator_tag,
                            std::pair<int&, int&> >
{
.
:
```

I get this error

```
multi_iter.cpp:12:53: error: template argument 2 is invalid
multi_iter.cpp:12:55: error: template argument 2 is invalid
multi_iter.cpp:12:55: error: template argument 4 is invalid
multi_iter.cpp:12:55: error: template argument 5 is invalid
.
:
```

I do have the std::pair

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You don't specialize `std::iterator`. You have to write your entire iterator class from ground up.

Comment: elaborate please: I should point out that this does work exactly like it should, when I specify the ints

Comment: @KerrekSB, actually, you can specialize `std::iterator` to get some convenient typedefs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/iterator/ . You have to provide all the function implementations though.

Comment: KerrekSB: the above code example was cut down to keep it relevant, I have implemented all of the functions required of output_iterator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value_type` is a dependent type on `IT1`, so you have to specify `typename` there

```
typename IT1::value_type
```

Comment: Where does he specialize anything?

Comment: I wish my compiler could of told me that: :S. But thank you that solved it :D

Comment: @111111 : For an explanation of why `typename` is needed, and how to know when to use it, see this FAQ: [What is the template `typename` keyword used for?](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename IT1, typename IT2>
struct multi_iter : public std::iterator<
                            std::output_iterator_tag,
                            std::pair<IT1::value_type&, IT2::value_type&> >
```

`IT1::value_type` is dependent on a type parameter and is a type, so it needs to be designated by `typename` keyword:

```
template<typename IT1, typename IT2>
struct multi_iter : public std::iterator<
                            std::output_iterator_tag,
                            std::pair<typename IT1::value_type&, typename IT2::value_type&> >
```

BTW if you want to "zip" two iterators (that is, iterate two sequences {1, 2} and {"a", "b"}, as (1, "a"), then (2, "b")), have a look at the [zip_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html) from the [boost.iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) library.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at zip_iterator, I did look for something like that. Although TBH this works now, and the disassembly show that it compiles out entirely :D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
template<typename IT1, typename IT2>
struct multi_iter : public std::iterator<
                            std::output_iterator_tag,
                            std::pair< typename IT1::value_type&, typename IT2::value_type& > >
{
.
:
```